# Prestashop 1.7.8.10 Adding a tab in the administration

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I would like to add a column in the order table of the order page from my module.

Currently I have this code:

```php
$tabNames = [];

foreach (Language::getLanguages(true) as $lang) {
    $tabNames[$lang['locale']] = $this->trans('Link List', array(), 'Modules.Linklist.Admin', $lang['locale']);
}
$this->tabs = [
    [
        'name' => [
            'en' => 'test',
            'fr' => 'test',
        ],
        'class_name' => 'AdminGamification',
        'parent_class_name' => 'AdminOrders',
    ],
];
```

If you have the solution, I'm interested!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The tabs defined in the `$this->tabs` property of your module class are read during module installation. You can try to reinstall the module from the Module Manager so that changes to the tabs property are taken into account ([docs](https://devdocs.prestashop-project.org/1.7/modules/concepts/controllers/admin-controllers/tabs/#how-to-check-the-tabs-registration)).